# Debugging: Line 126: Syntax Error Unexpected End

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, javascript-objects

I'm receiving an error in my JS/HTML5 pong gaming project on line 126:

```
tennisJS_game.html:126 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

I can't see where I went wrong. I closed the function and everything else looks good.

Below is my code

```
var canvas;
var canvasContext;
var ballX = 50;
var ballY = 50;
var ballSpeedX = 10;
var ballSpeedY = 4;

var paddle1Y = 250;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100; 
// C Programming #define (ALWAYS CONSTANT)

/*
Observing returning event (evt) of mouse positioning coordinates in relation to where the mouse is on the "gameCanvas"
For example starting point on the "gameCanvas" is on (0,0) on the (y,x) axis
EventListener wouldn't care about mouse position or "mousePos" if this code wasn't here
Two piece of data are being returned here... mouseX and mouseY
*/

function calculateMousePos(evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var root = document.documentElement;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    return {
        x:mouseX,
        y:mouseY
        };

}

//variables section


//Speed of objects & EventListener & Resetting the Ball section

window.onload = function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var framesPerSecond = 30;
    setInterval(function() {
        moveEverything();
        drawEverything();
      }, 1000/framesPerSecond );

    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
        function(evt) {
            var mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
            paddle1Y = mousePos.y-(PADDLE_HEIGHT/2); //So players mouse and paddle relationship position is center
            });
}

function moveEverything() {
    ballX = ballX + ballSpeedX;
    ballY = ballY + ballSpeedY
    if(ballX < 0) {
        if(ballY > paddle1Y &&
        ballY < paddle1Y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) {
                ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        } else {
        ballReset();    }

    if(ballX > canvas.width) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    }

    if(ballY < 0) {
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }
    if(ballY > canvas.height) {
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }

//Speed of objects & EventListener & Resetting the Ball section


function colorRect(leftX,topY,width,height,drawColor) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
    canvasContext.fillRect(leftX,topY, width, height);
}

//Ball Reset f(x) section

function ballReset() {
     ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    ballX = canvas.width/2;
    ballY = canvas.height/2;
}



//Ball Reset f(x) section



//canvas arguments/parameters

function drawEverything () {

    // next line blanks out the screen with black
    colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');

    // this left player paddle
    colorRect(0,paddle1Y,10,100,'white');

    // next line draws the ball
    colorCircle(ballX,ballY,10,'white');
}



function colorCircle(centerX,centerY,radius, drawColor) {
    canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    canvasContext.fill();}



//canvas arguments/parameters
```

Comment: Brackers for the function `moveEverything` haven't been closed correctly.

Comment: And also for `if(ballX < 0) {` there is no closing bracket.

Comment: Just put two closing braces `}}` at end of file

Comment: @JeremyRedkey. Since your question is resolved, you might either post the solution as an answer and then accept your own answer. Or delete your question. Either of these 2 options will take your question off the "unanswered questions" queue. Thanks! :-)

Comment: First approach is to use an editor which highlights errors and indents for you. Are you doing that? Failing that, the classic approach is "divide and conquer"--keep removing parts of your code until you find the part that was causing the problem. If you intend to do much JS programming (or programming in any language for that matter), you should make it a priority to learn these two approaches, since you can't post to SO every time you make a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets for the function moveEverything haven't been closed correctly. – Nehal J Wani Aug 28 at 7:06

And also for if(ballX < 0) { there is no closing bracket. – Nehal J Wani Aug 28 at 7:06